# Running multiple instances of single parameter report at once

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, instance, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that takes one parameter (an order no) and creates a document for that order, pulling in some address fields, etc.

My customers want the ability to select multiple order numbers at once and print out say 10 different sheets, one for each order.  everything would be the same on each sheet, save for the order specific information.

my problem is that currently, toggling the parameter to accept multiple values jams all the information for all 10 orders into the same place on one instance of the report.  Is there a way around this?

Please let me know any and all further clarification or examples you need.

Comment: Are you grouping on anything? try grouping on an order number, add page breaks between instances of the group.

Comment: Everything on the report is static, save for a tablix and text box with two expressions.  When I tried grouping on order # before and adding page breaks, it still uses only one instance of the report, and jams the info for all orders into the same place just breaking it up between

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a sub-report to run the same report multiple times with different parameters.

- Create a new report with a multi-value parameter for the order #'s.
- Add a tablix that uses the multi-value parameter to display each order #.
- Replace the field that displays the order # with a sub-report.
- Wire-up the sub-report to point to your original report and pass in the order #.

To make sure each report prints on a different page:

- Group by order # in the tablix (shouldn't change the tablix output if each order # is unique)
- Right click the Row Group and select "Group Properties"
- Choose "Page Breaks" and check the box "Between each instance of a group"

Comment: This does the trick! Thanks so much, spent way too much time trying to figure this out.  Your response was clear and simple.