# Can you use the group function on a rectangle in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, group-by, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to create several copies of a report all at once, so I have dropped all my elements in a rectangle.  I was hoping I could set a group by function on the rectangle.. is this possible? Right clicking the rectangle and selecting properties, I do not see the same group option that most other objects have.

Comment: In SSRS you cannot set grouping options for a rectangle, what do you want to see in the rectangle? maybe there is a workaround.

Comment: I have a report that runs fine.  I want to be able to run the report for several different parameter instances at once, but my problem is that it puts all relevant information for each parameter in the same spot, as opposed to creating a different page for each one.

Comment: Set a page break between groups.

Comment: You might be looking for "Lists". https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239330.aspx

Comment: This problem was solved using the answer on [this related thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048661/running-multiple-instances-of-single-parameter-report-at-once).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be resolved with this approach:

- Create a new report with a multi-value parameter for the order #'s.
- Add a tablix that uses the multi-value parameter to display each
  order #.
- Replace the field that displays the order # with a
  sub-report.
- Wire-up the sub-report to point to your original report
  and pass in the order #.
- Group by order # in the tablix (shouldn't change the tablix output if each order # is unique)
- Right click the Row Group and select "Group Properties"
- Choose "Page Breaks" and check the box "Between each instance of a group"